# Getting output of system() calls in Ruby

Tags: ruby, system, call

If I call a command using [Kernel#system](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) in Ruby, how do I get its output?

```
system("ls")
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this thread in comp.lang.ruby](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_thread/thread/a274d5d47feae95?pli=1)

Comment: This is a very hand thread, thanks. The class for running commands and getting feedback is great in the sample code.

Comment: For future googlers. If you want to learn about other system command calls and their differences, [see this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18623297/52317).

Answer (score 390, accepted):

I'd like to expand & clarify [chaos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/690174/56763) a bit.

If you surround your command with backticks, then you don't need to (explicitly) call system() at all. The backticks execute the command and return the output as a string. You can then assign the value to a variable like so:

```
output = `ls`
p output
```

or

```
printf output # escapes newline chars
```

Comment: what if I need to give a variable as part of my command? That is, what would something like system("ls " + filename) translate into when backticks are to be used?

Comment: You can do expression evaluation just as you would with regular strings: `ls #{filename}`.

Comment: Hrm, makdown ate my formatting. There are back ticks ahead of the "l" in "ls" and after the "}" in "#{filename}".

Comment: Craig - in markdown you can quote with the backslash character: `\`ls #{filename}\``

Comment: Does this capture all output?

Comment: No, it only captures stdout, not stderr.

Comment: This answer isn't advisable: it introduces the new problem of unsanitized user input.

Comment: @Dogweather: that may be true, but is it any different than any of the other methods?

Comment: if you want to capure stderr just put 2>&1 at the end of your command. e.g output = `command 2>&1`

Comment: I think the answer @martin-gross provides is the cleaner solution; while both work, this is what `%x` is for.

Comment: backticks is not equivalent to system, you can't pass environment, you can separate stdout and stderrr etc

Comment: @CraigWalker: I think micred's comment should be added to your answer. It's rather helpful.

if you want to capure stderr just put 2>&1 at the end of your command. e.g output = command 2>&1

Comment: It's often necessary to cut a trailing newline with `output = \`ls\`.tr("\n","")`

Comment: @Dogweather It only introduces unsanitized user input if variables with user input that hasn't yet been sanitized are used.  An experienced Ruby programmer would be careful to label relevant vars (e.g. `filename_sane` or `filename_escd`) and only use those in dangerous contexts such as this.

Comment: Does anyone know whether the backtick operator is actually thread-safe? That is, if I pass different commands from different threads to it, and store the output in thread-local variables, are the variables guaranteed to only contain the output from the command I called in a particular thread, or might the output be manged with the output form command I called in another thread?

Comment: @CraigWalker. Your printf is not syntactically correct.

Comment: Backticks are perfectly fine in a program that does not accept user input, such as the one shown here. The only way to modify the system call is to modify the source, and if someone can modify the source, well...

Comment: Be aware that using system and backticks, are similar, but not the same.  When in doubt, try both.

Comment: This works only if you command is static. If you try to build dynamic command like "ls #{directory_path}" it wont work.

Answer (score 265):

Be aware that all the solutions where you pass a string containing user provided values to `system`, `%x[]` etc. are unsafe! Unsafe actually means: the user may trigger code to run in the context and with all permissions of the program.

As far as I can say only `system` and `Open3.popen3` do provide a secure/escaping variant in Ruby 1.8. In Ruby 1.9 `IO::popen` also accepts an array.

Simply pass every option and argument as an array to one of these calls.

If you need not just the exit status but also the result you probably want to use `Open3.popen3`:

```
require 'open3'
stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3('usermod', '-p', @options['shadow'], @options['username'])
stdout.gets(nil)
stdout.close
stderr.gets(nil)
stderr.close
exit_code = wait_thr.value
```

Note that the block form will auto-close stdin, stdout and stderr- otherwise they'd have to be [closed explicitly](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3).

More information here: [Forming sanitary shell commands or system calls in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650636/forming-sanitary-shell-commands-or-system-calls-in-ruby)

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question and solves the problem without introducing new ones (unsanitized input).

Comment: Thanks!  This is the sort of answer I was hoping for.  One correction: the `gets` calls should pass the argument `nil`, as otherwise we just get the first line of the output. So e.g. `stdout.gets(nil)`.

Comment: stdin, stdout and stderr should be [closed explicitly in non-block form](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3).

Comment: Does anybody know if something changed in Ruby 2.0 or 2.1? Edits or comments would be appreciated;-)

Comment: I think that the discussion around `Open3.popen3` is missing a major problem: If you have a subprocess that writes more data to stdout than a pipe can hold, subprocess gets suspend in `stderr.write`, and your program gets stuck in `stdout.gets(nil)`.

Comment: @simon I am using the same code but I dont know for some reason in nginx+passenger the application is not waiting for the response from the script I dont know what is happening, please check the issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696685/rails-controller-returning-nil-response-while-running-casperjs-test-cases-with-s

Comment: block form here (near bottom): https://makandracards.com/makandra/44452-running-external-commands-with-open3. Note that the string marked '/some/command' should include all the arguments. I was trying stdin.puts "my arguments", but that's only needed if the executed command consumes user input

Answer (score 181):

Just for the record, if you want both (output and operation result) you can do:

```
output=`ls no_existing_file` ;  result=$?.success?
```

Comment: That only captures stdout, and stderr goes to the console.

To get stderr, use:

`output=\`ls no_existing_file 2>&1\`; result=$?.success?`

Comment: This answer is **unsafe** and shouldn't be used -- if the command is anything but a constant, then the backtick syntax is likely to cause a bug, possibly a security vulnerability. (And even if it is a constant, it will probably cause someone to use it for a non-constant later and cause a bug.) See [Simon Hürlimann's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5970819/378130) for a correct solution.

Comment: kudos to Greg Price for understanding about the need to escape user input, but it is not correct to say this answer as written is unsafe. The Open3 method mentioned is more complicated and introduces more dependencies, and the argument that someone will "use it for a non-constant later" is a strawman. True, you probably wouldn't use them in a Rails app, but for a simple system utility script with no possibility of untrusted user input, backticks are perfectly fine and nobody should be made to feel bad about using them.

Comment: Two major issues with this solution are 1. **user input is not escaped** 2. `$?` is a global variable and thus I think it is **not thread-safe**

Answer (score 91):

The straightforward way to do this correctly and securely is to use [`Open3.capture2()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture2), [`Open3.capture2e()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture2e), or [`Open3.capture3()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3).

Using ruby's backticks and its `%x` alias are **NOT SECURE UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES** if used with untrusted data. It is **DANGEROUS**, plain and simple:

```
untrusted = "; date; echo"
out = `echo #{untrusted}`                              # BAD

untrusted = '"; date; echo"'
out = `echo "#{untrusted}"`                            # BAD

untrusted = "'; date; echo'"
out = `echo '#{untrusted}'`                            # BAD
```

The `system` function, in contrast, escapes arguments properly **if used correctly**:

```
ret = system "echo #{untrusted}"                       # BAD
ret = system 'echo', untrusted                         # good
```

Trouble is, it returns the exit code instead of the output, and capturing the latter is convoluted and messy.

The best answer in this thread so far mentions Open3, but not the functions that are best suited for the task. `Open3.capture2`, `capture2e` and `capture3` work like `system`, but returns two or three arguments:

```
out, err, st = Open3.capture3("echo #{untrusted}")     # BAD
out, err, st = Open3.capture3('echo', untrusted)       # good
out_err, st  = Open3.capture2e('echo', untrusted)      # good
out, st      = Open3.capture2('echo', untrusted)       # good
p st.exitstatus
```

Another mentions [`IO.popen()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-popen). The syntax can be clumsy in the sense that it wants an array as input, but it works too:

```
out = IO.popen(['echo', untrusted]).read               # good
```

---

For convenience, you can wrap `Open3.capture3()` in a function, e.g.:

```
#
# Returns stdout on success, false on failure, nil on error
#
def syscall(*cmd)
  begin
    stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(*cmd)
    status.success? && stdout.slice!(0..-(1 + $/.size)) # strip trailing eol
  rescue
  end
end
```

Example:

```
p system('foo')
p syscall('foo')
p system('which', 'foo')
p syscall('which', 'foo')
p system('which', 'which')
p syscall('which', 'which')
```

Yields the following:

```
nil
nil
false
false
/usr/bin/which         <— stdout from system('which', 'which')
true                   <- p system('which', 'which')
"/usr/bin/which"       <- p syscall('which', 'which')
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  It is also the most informative.  The only thing missing is a warning about closing the std*s.

See [this other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21071595/213191):

```require 'open3';
output = Open3.popen3("ls") { |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr| stdout.read }```

Note that the block form will auto-close stdin, stdout and stderr- otherwise they'd have to be [closed explicitly](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3).

Comment: @PeterH.Boling: Best I'm aware, the `capture2`, `capture2e` and `capture3` also close them std*s automatically. (At the very least, I never ran into the problem on my end.)

Comment: without using the block form there is no way for a codebase to know when something should be closed, so I *highly* doubt they are being closed.  You probably never ran into a problem because not closing them won't cause problems in a short lived process, and if you restart a long-running process often enough, otto won't show up there either unless you are opening std*s in a loop.  Linux has a high file descriptor limit, which you can hit, but until you hit it you won't see the "bug".

Comment: @PeterH.Boling: No no, see the source code. The functions are just wrappers around `Open3#popen2`, `popen2e` and `popen3` with a predefined block: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture2

Comment: @Dennis de Barnardy Perhaps you missed that I linked to the same class documentation (albeit for Ruby 2.0.0, and a different method.  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3

From the example:
```
stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3([env,] cmd... [, opts])
pid = wait_thr[:pid]  # pid of the started process
...
stdin.close  # stdin, stdout and stderr should be closed explicitly in this form.
stdout.close
stderr.close
```

I was just quoting the documentation. "# stdin, stdout and stderr should be closed explicitly in this form."

Comment: `echo "#{untrusted}"` (with the double quotes) is **not** safe. Let `untrusted` be `"; date; echo"`.

Comment: Good catch @AndreasKrey!

Answer (score 61):

You can use system() or %x[] depending what kind of result you need.

system() returning true if the command was found and ran successfully, false otherwise.

```
>> s = system 'uptime'
10:56  up 3 days, 23:10, 2 users, load averages: 0.17 0.17 0.14
=> true
>> s.class
=> TrueClass
>> $?.class
=> Process::Status
```

%x[..] on the other hand saves the results of the command as a string:

```
>> result = %x[uptime]
=> "13:16  up 4 days,  1:30, 2 users, load averages: 0.39 0.29 0.23\n"
>> p result 
"13:16  up 4 days,  1:30, 2 users, load averages: 0.39 0.29 0.23\n"
>> result.class
=> String
```

Th [blog post by Jay Fields](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html) explains in detail the differences between using system, exec and %x[..] .

Comment: Thanks for the tip of using %x[]. It just solved a problem I had where I used back ticks in a ruby script in Mac OS X. When running the same script on a Windows machine with Cygwin, it failed because of the back ticks, but worked with %x[].

Comment: Thanks a lot! `%x[..]` it's the compact and working solution!

Answer (score 28):

If you need to escape the arguments, in Ruby 1.9 [IO.popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-popen) also accepts an array:

```
p IO.popen(["echo", "it's escaped"]).read
```

In earlier versions you can use [Open3.popen3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3):

```
require "open3"

Open3.popen3("echo", "it's escaped") { |i, o| p o.read }
```

If you also need to pass stdin, this should work in both 1.9 and 1.8:

```
out = IO.popen("xxd -p", "r+") { |io|
    io.print "xyz"
    io.close_write
    io.read.chomp
}
p out # "78797a"
```

Answer (score 21):

You use backticks:

```
`ls`
```

Comment: Backticks do not produce output at the terminal.

Comment: It doesn't produce stderr but it gives stdout.

Comment: It doesn't write to stdout or stderr. Let's try this example `ruby -e '%x{ls}'` - note, no output. (fyi `%x{}` is equivalent to backticks.)

Comment: This worked great. Using `sh` would echo the output to the console (i.e. STDOUT) as well as return it. This doesn't.

Answer (score 20):

Another way is:

```
f = open("|ls")
foo = f.read()
```

Note that's the "pipe" character before "ls" in open. This can also be used to feed data into the programs standard input as well as reading its standard output.

Comment: Just used this to read standard output from an aws cli command in order to read the json and not the official return value of 'true'

Answer (score 16):

I found that the following is useful if you need the return value:

```
result = %x[ls]
puts result
```

I specifically wanted to list the pids of all the Java processes on my machine, and used this:

```
ids = %x[ps ax | grep java | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs]
```

Comment: It's a great solution.

Answer (score 16):

As [Simon Hürlimann already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5970819/165673), [Open3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) is safer than backticks etc.

```
require 'open3'
output = Open3.popen3("ls") { |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr| stdout.read }
```

Note that the block form will auto-close stdin, stdout and stderr- otherwise they'd have to be [closed explicitly](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3).

Comment: Simple and beautiful

Answer (score 15):

While using backticks or popen is often what you really want, it doesn't actually answer the question asked. There may be valid reasons for capturing `system` output (maybe for automated testing). A little Googling [turned up an answer](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t812652-redirect-stdout-for-kernel-system.html) I thought I would post here for the benefit of others.

Since I needed this for testing my example uses a block setup to capture the standard output since the actual `system` call is buried in the code being tested:

```
require 'tempfile'

def capture_stdout
  stdout = $stdout.dup
  Tempfile.open 'stdout-redirect' do |temp|
    $stdout.reopen temp.path, 'w+'
    yield if block_given?
    $stdout.reopen stdout
    temp.read
  end
end
```

This method captures any output in the given block using a tempfile to store the actual data. Example usage:

```
captured_content = capture_stdout do
  system 'echo foo'
end
puts captured_content
```

You can replace the `system` call with anything that internally calls `system`. You could also use a similar method to capture `stderr` if you wanted.

Answer (score 10):

If you want the output redirected to a file using `Kernel#system`, you can do modify descriptors like this:

redirect stdout and stderr to a file(/tmp/log) in append mode:

`system('ls -al', :out => ['/tmp/log', 'a'], :err => ['/tmp/log', 'a'])`

For a long running command, this will store the output in real time. You can also, store the output using a IO.pipe and redirect it from Kernel#system.

Answer (score 7):

As a direct system(...) replacement you may use Open3.popen3(...)

Further discussion:
http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution to capture standard output into a variable named **val**:

```
val = capture(:stdout) do
  system("pwd")
end

puts val
```

shortened version:

```
val = capture(:stdout) { system("ls") }
```

**capture** method is provided by
*active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb*

Simlarly we can also capture standard errors too with `:stderr`

Comment: `capture` was removed from Rails version 5 and above, for thread safety reasons. See PR https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13392

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep using `system` you can redirect the output to a pipe:

```rb
r, w = IO.pipe
system("ls", out: w)
w.close
output = r.read
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find this one here so adding it, I had some issues getting the full output.

> You can redirect STDERR to STDOUT if you want to capture STDERR using
>   backtick.
>
> output = `grep hosts /private/etc/* 2>&1`

source: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/10/18/backtick-system-exec-in-ruby.html

Answer (score 1):

Short answer for most convenient way is:

```rb
    require 'open3'

    stdout_str, stderr_str, status = Open3.capture3(cmd)
    puts "exit status: #{status.exitstatus} stdout: #{stdout_str}"
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a gem, called *Frontkick***

```rb
Frontkick.exec("echo *")
```

And here is how to check and read it:

```rb
result = Frontkick.exec("echo *")

puts result.successful? #=> true if exit_code is 0
puts result.success?    #=> alias to successful?, for compatibility with Process::Status
puts result.stdout      #=> stdout output of the command
puts result.stderr      #=> stderr output of the command
puts result.exit_code   #=> exit_code of the command
puts result.status      #=> alias to exit_code
puts result.exitstatus  #=> alias to exit_code, for compatibility with Process::Status
puts result.duration    #=> the time used to execute the command
```

Github https://github.com/sonots/frontkick#frontkick

Gem Page https://rubygems.org/gems/frontkick

Answer (score -1):

```
puts `date`
puts $?


Mon Mar  7 19:01:15 PST 2016
pid 13093 exit 0
```