# Return output from "system" command in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have to execute a shell command from Ruby script but I have to retrieve the output so that I can use it in the script later on.

Here is my code:

```
output = system "heroku create" # => true
```

But the system command returns a boolean and not the output.

Simply said, system "heroku create" has to output to my screen (which it does) but also return the output so I can process it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use

```
output = `heroku create`
```

See: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html

Comment: is it the same as %x("heroku create") ?

Comment: @ajsie According to the manual, "The built-in syntax `%x{…}` uses this method. "

Answer (score 9):

The Open3 library gives you full access to the standard IO streams (STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR).
It's part of Ruby, so there's no need to install a gem:

```
require 'open3'

stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3("heroku create")
puts stdout.read
stdin.close; stdout.close; stderr.close
```

or you can use the block form which closes the streams implicitely:

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3("heroku create") do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
    puts stdout.read
end
```

See the [Open3 documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) for the full details.

Edit: Added extra stream closing details. Thanks Christopher and Gregory.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to `close` these? I'm looking for documentation on this, and none of the examples show whether or not you have to. (Sorry: python, C#, c++ background, all of which require you to use an alternate syntax or manually close streams).

Comment: You're right, @ChristopherPfohl: from the docs, `stdin/out/err.close  # stdin, stdout and stderr should be closed explicitly in this form.`. However, you can also use the block form which will be auto-closed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following:

```
output = capture(:stdout) do
  system("pwd") # your system command goes here
end

puts output
```

shortened version:

```
output = capture(:stdout) { system("pwd") }
```

Similarly we can also capture standard errors too with `:stderr`

**capture** method is provided by *active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb*

Looking at that library's code comments, **capture** is going to be deprecated, so not sure what is the current supported method name is.