# Forming sanitary shell commands or system calls in Ruby

Tags: ruby, security, shell, system, sanitization

I'm building a daemon that will help me manage my server(s). Webmin works fine, as does just opening a shell to the server, but I'd prefer to be able to control server operations from a UI I design, and also expose some functionality to end users.

The daemon will pick up actions from a queue and execute them. However, since I'll be accepting input from users, I want to make sure they're not permitted to inject something dangerous into a privileged shell command.

Here's a fragment that exemplifies my problem:

```
def perform
  system "usermod -p #{@options['shadow']} #{@options['username']}"
end
```

A gist that explains more: https://gist.github.com/773292

I'm not positive if typical escaping and sanitizing of inputs is enough for this case, and being a designer, I don't have a ton of security-related experience. **I know that this is something that should probably be obvious to me**, but its not!

How can I ensure that the web application that will create and serialize the actions can't pass dangerous text into the privileged process that receives the actions?

Thanks for the help
arb

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need a shell for what you're doing.  See the documentation for `system` here: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001441

You should use the second form of `system`.  Your example above would become:

```
system 'usermod', '-p', @options['shadow'], @options['username']
```

A nicer (IMO) way to write this is:

```
system *%W(usermod -p #{@options['shadow']} #{@options['username']})
```

The arguments this way are passed directly into the `execve` call, so you don't have to worry about sneaky shell tricks.

Comment: so, let's say if I exposed this class, completely unfiltered (I won't) to an end user, and they provided a shadow hash and then "username; rm -rf /" as the username — this wouldn't have the effect of obliterating `/`

Comment: ah, well great. It does make perfect sense. I think I have this thought that ensuring an application is secure must naturally be harder than it is, harder than simple steps and facts, as if there exists a dangerous edge case for everything. This is likely because I've never read / learned very much about it.

Comment: this also has the added benefit of using system calls, instead of making the calls through bash and then to the system (saves a little overhead on top of the sanitization)

Comment: The example given by above should read `ruby -e 'system *%w(ls -l foo; rm -rf /)'` instead.

Answer (score 17):

If you need not just the exit status but also the result you probably want to use `Open3.popen3`:

```
require 'open3'
stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3('usermod', '-p', @options['shadow'], @options['username'])
stdout.gets
sterr.gets
```

More information here: [Getting output of system() calls in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looking into the 'shellwords' module.  This script:

```
require 'shellwords'
parts = ['echo', "'hello world'; !%& some stuff", 'and another argument']
command = Shellwords.shelljoin( parts )
puts command
output = `#{ command }`
puts output
```

outputs the escaped text and the expected output:

```
echo \'hello\ world\'\;\ \!\%\&\ some\ stuff and\ another\ argument
'hello world'; !%& some stuff and another argument
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but since it's pretty much the only real answer you'll find when googling I thought I'd add a caveat. The multi argument version of system seems reasonably safe on Linux, but it is NOT on Windows.

Try `system "dir", "&", "echo", "hi!"`
on a Windows system. Both dir and echo will be run. Echo could of course just as well be something far less innocuous.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but there is another option that was lightly touched on by **Simon Hürlimann**.

There is not a lot of information about this topic and I think this might help others in need.

For this example we'll use `Open3` which gives you the ability to run commands synchronously or asynchronously, and provides **stdout**, **stderr**, **exit codes**, and **PID**.

Open3 grants you access to stdout, stderr, exit codes and a thread to wait for the child process when running another program. You can specify various attributes, redirections, current directory, etc., of the program in the same way as for Process.spawn. (*Source: [Open3 Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html))*

I chose to format the output as a `CommandStatus` object. This contains our `stdout`, `stderr`, `pid` (Of the worker thread) and `exitstatus`.

```
class Command
  require 'open3'

  class CommandStatus
    @stdout     = nil
    @stderr     = nil
    @pid        = nil
    @exitstatus = nil

    def initialize(stdout, stderr, process)
      @stdout     = stdout
      @stderr     = stderr
      @pid        = process.pid
      @exitstatus = process.exitstatus
    end

    def stdout
      @stdout
    end

    def stderr
      @stderr
    end

    def exit_status
      @exitstatus
    end

    def pid
      @pid
    end
  end

  def self.execute(command)
    command_stdout = nil
    command_stderr = nil
    process = Open3.popen3(ENV, command + ';') do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|
      stdin.close
      stdout_buffer   = stdout.read
      stderr_buffer   = stderr.read
      command_stdout  = stdout_buffer if stdout_buffer.length > 0
      command_stderr  = stderr_buffer if stderr_buffer.length > 0
      thread.value # Wait for Process::Status object to be returned
    end
    return CommandStatus.new(command_stdout, command_stderr, process)
  end
end


cmd = Command::execute("echo {1..10}")

puts "STDOUT: #{cmd.stdout}"
puts "STDERR: #{cmd.stderr}"
puts "EXIT: #{cmd.exit_status}"
```

While reading the STDOUT/ERR buffers, I use `command_stdout  = stdout_buffer if stdout_buffer.length > 0` to control whether the `command_stdout` variable is assigned or not. You should pass `nil` instead of `""` when no data is present. It's more clear when handing data later on.

You probably noticed me using `command + ';'`. The reason for this is based on the documentation from Kernel.exec (Which is what popen3 uses):

> If the string from the first form (exec("command")) follows these
>   simple rules:
>
> - no meta characters
> - no shell reserved word and no special built-in
> - Ruby invokes the command directly without shell
>
> You can force shell invocation by adding ";" to the string (because
>   ";" is a meta character)

This simply prevents a Ruby from throwing a `'spawn': No such file or directory` error if you pass a malformed command. Instead it will pass it straight to the kernel where the error will be resolved gracefully and appear as STDERR instead of an uncaught exception.

Answer (score 0):

Modern, secure and simple solution (`popen` will escape arguments for you):

```rb
IO.popen(['usermod', '-p', @options['shadow'], @options['username']]).read
```

(`#read` will close the IO before returning)