# How do I sanitize shell command and get the output in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, shell, sanitize

I have to run some shell commands where the user gives the input. I found one way which seemed secure: `system *%W(ls #{file})` [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650636/forming-sanitary-shell-commands-or-system-calls-in-ruby).

I need to get the output of that command, so I cant just use `system`. Is there a way to sanitize the command for backticks ``` `` ``` or for `%x[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`IO::popen`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html) instead of `system`.  You  can still pass an array of strings to invoke the command without a shell, and you can `read` from the resulting IO object.

If you want to read stderr too, then use the [`open3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html) module instead of IO.

Comment: IO::popen(*%W[ls -al]).read gives me "ArgumentError: illegal access mode -al" :( but without '-al' it works...

Comment: @klump, remove the `*` so that the first argument to popen is an array.

Comment: Note that calling `popen` with an array works in 1.9 only. In ruby 1.8 you'd need to use popen3 or backticks + `Shellwords.escape`.

Comment: @sepp2k: Does backports cover this?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of shell commands are you running that Ruby cannot support? If you are listing files, use [Dir](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html)

Comment: i was using ls just as an exsample, i want to use a mix of selfwritten programms and unix programms, i am using the ruby File, Dir and FileUtils classes :P