# Background tasks and shell commands from a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am looking to frequently create 3 background tasks and execute some shell commands from these tasks from my Rails app. I was thinking about using delayed_job for the background tasks but I am unsure as to how to safely execute shell commands from a rails app, can someone tell me how I can do this from a Rails app?

Jeff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways,  all are Rubyisms.

```
system('cmd','arg1',...)
```

Or the very Unixy

```
val = `ls -l`
```

The latter would run the command and return it's output into the variable val.

Comment: I am aware of system() and back ticks but this seems like a bad idea. What I mean is is there anything for Ruby/Rails like http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess? (My background is/was py) Running system commands from a privileged process such as apache seems like a security issue so I was hoping to find something similar or equivalent to the subprocess module from python.

Comment: It's a potential security hole,  you just have to make sure whatever get's handed to system is validated.  I use it extensively,  but anything passed to system never comes from user input, so it works for me.  Here's a relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650636/forming-sanitary-shell-commands-or-system-calls-in-ruby

Comment: great! none of the data comes from my users as well but am always concerned about ANY security holes. I will investigate this solutions, thanks rad