# Can I get continuous output from system calls in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, bash, scripting, scp

When you use a system call in a Ruby script, you can get the output of that command like this:

```
output = `ls`
puts output
```

That's what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby) was about.

But is there a way to show the **continuous** output of a system call? For example, if you run this secure copy command, to get a file from a server over SSH:

```
scp user@someserver:remoteFile /some/local/folder/
```

... it shows continuous output with the progress of the download. But this:

```
output = `scp user@someserver:remoteFile /some/local/folder/`
puts output
```

... doesn't capture that output.

**How can I show the ongoing progress of the download from inside my Ruby script?**

Comment: you had two orthogonal problems here, because scp only outputs to terminals by default, you need *scp -v*

Comment: @tokland - that gets it to output debugging messages, but not the transfer progress that I would see if I just ran scp alone. I think those must not go to standard output, and I don't see an option for scp to send them there.

Comment: Apparently scp sends that progress info to "interactive terminal"? Not sure how to capture that...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
IO.popen("scp -v user@server:remoteFile /local/folder/").each do |fd|
  puts(fd.readline)
end
```

Comment: This works for getting standard output messages, but it appears that's not where scp is sending its transfer progress. So I guess my problem is with scp now.

Comment: This answers the question as I asked it - the fact that scp doesn't do normal output turned out to be an unexpected detail.

Comment: See my answer below for how I was able to get that output from the Ruby standard library.

Answer (score 3):

I think you would have better luck using the ruby standard library to handle SCP (as opposed to forking a shell process).  The Net::SCP library (as well as the entire Net::* libraries) are full featured and used with Capistrano to handle remote commands.

Checkout http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/ for a rundown of what is available.

Comment: This looks really promising! The net-scp documentation is here: http://net-ssh.github.com/scp/v1/api/index.html Also, this tutorial shows how to output progress during the transfer: http://ruby.about.com/od/ssh/ss/netscp_4.htm

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I was able to show a running counter of the download progress by passing a block to to scp object. See my answer for the complete script.

Answer (score 2):

Tokland answered the question as I asked it, but Adam's approach was what I ended up using. Here was my completed script, which **does** show a running count of bytes downloaded, and also a percentage complete.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/scp'
puts "Fetching file"

# Establish the SSH session
ssh = Net::SSH.start("IP Address", "username on server", :password => "user's password on server", :port => 12345)

# Use that session to generate an SCP object
scp = ssh.scp

# Download the file and run the code block each time a new chuck of data is received
scp.download!("path/to/file/on/server/fileName", "/Users/me/Desktop/") do |ch, name, received, total|

  # Calculate percentage complete and format as a two-digit percentage
  percentage = format('%.2f', received.to_f / total.to_f * 100) + '%'

  # Print on top of (replace) the same line in the terminal
  # - Pad with spaces to make sure nothing remains from the previous output
  # - Add a carriage return without a line feed so the line doesn't move down
  print "Saving to #{name}: Received #{received} of #{total} bytes" + " (#{percentage})               \r"

  # Print the output immediately - don't wait until the buffer fills up
  STDOUT.flush
end

puts "Fetch complete!"
```

Comment: yeah, this is the best approach, when using good languages is only logical to rely on their libraries.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with IO.popen ?
you should be able to read the output while the process is still running and parse it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting stderr to stdout may work for you:

```
output = `scp user@someserver:remoteFile /some/local/folder/ 2>&1`
puts output
```

That should capture both stderr and stdout. You can capture stderr only by throwing away stdout:

```
output = `scp user@someserver:remoteFile /some/local/folder/ 2>&1 >/dev/null`
puts output
```

You can then use `IO.popen`.