# Ruby, Difference between exec, system and %x() or Backticks

Tags: ruby, exec

What is the difference between the following Ruby methods?

`exec`, `system` and `%x()` or *Backticks*

I know they are used to execute terminal commands programmatically via Ruby, but I'd like to know why there are three different ways to do this.

Comment: These commands, and many others, are explained quite well in the docs: [exec](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) [system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system) [backticks](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-60)

Comment: There is a great Ruby Quicktips article on that topic: [Execute shell commands](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands).

Comment: Since someone just dug up this old thread, "Working With Unix Processes" is an excellent book for Rubyists interested in the topic: http://workingwithunixprocesses.com/

Comment: I'm surprised none of the answers mention [`sh`](http://apidock.com/ruby/FileUtils/sh).

Comment: @Dennis When I was raising this question ruby 1.9.3* not released.

Comment: @Dennis sh wraps a shell (likely $SHELL) around whatever you're running.  Somebody please explain when this is useful / necessary :)

Answer (score 476, accepted):

**system**

The [`system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system) method calls a system program. You have to provide the command as a string argument to  this method. For example:

```
>> system("date")
Wed Sep 4 22:03:44 CEST 2013
=> true
```

The invoked program will use the current `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` objects of your Ruby program. In fact, the actual return value is either `true`, `false` or `nil`. In the example the date was printed through the IO object of `STDIN`. The method will return `true` if the process exited with a zero status, `false` if the process exited with a non-zero status and `nil` if the execution failed.

As of Ruby 2.6, passing `exception: true` will raise an exception instead of returning `false` or `nil`:

```
>> system('invalid')
=> nil

>> system('invalid', exception: true)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - invalid)
```

Another side effect is that the global variable `$?` is set to a [`Process::Status`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Process/Status.html) object. This object will contain information about the  call itself, including the process identifier (PID) of the invoked process and the exit status.

```
>> system("date")
Wed Sep 4 22:11:02 CEST 2013
=> true
>> $?
=> #<Process::Status: pid 15470 exit 0>
```

**Backticks**

[Backticks](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-60) (``) call a system program and return its output. As opposed to the first approach, the command is not provided through a string, but by putting it inside a backticks pair.

```
>> `date`
=> Wed Sep 4 22:22:51 CEST 2013
```

The global variable `$?` is set through the backticks, too. With backticks you can also make use string interpolation.

**%x()**

Using `%x` is an alternative to the backticks style. It will return the output, too. Like its relatives `%w` and `%q` (among others), any delimiter will suffice as long as bracket-style delimiters match. This means `%x(date)`, `%x{date}` and `%x-date-` are all synonyms. Like backticks `%x` can make use of string interpolation.

**exec**

By using [`Kernel#exec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) the current process (your Ruby script) is replaced with the process invoked through `exec`. The method can take a string as argument. In this case the string will be subject to shell expansion. When using more than one argument, then the first one is used to execute a program and the following are provided as arguments to the program to be invoked.

**Open3.popen3**

Sometimes the required information is written to standard input or standard error and you need to get control over those as well. Here [`Open3.popen3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) comes in handy:

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3("curl http://example.com") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|
   pid = thread.pid
   puts stdout.read.chomp
end
```

Comment: And for more fine-grained control of how the call handles `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, `STDERR`, consider `Open3.popen3` instead; e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10922097/258662

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that backticks support string interpolation which solved my problem.

Answer (score 326):

Here's a flowchart based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7263556/2063546).  See also, [using `script` to emulate a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1402389/2063546).

[image]

Comment: This is not so simple. In my case it "was OK (and need) to block until the process complete" to then use popen3 to check the STDOUT/STDERR outputs.

Comment: You can always cause a non-blocking call to (effectively) block by wrapping it in a while loop.  You can't make a blocking call into a non-blocking call so easily.

Comment: Typical StackOverflow - everyone is critical but honestly this flow chart is so handy and helped me immensely. Thanks.

Answer (score 119):

They do different things.  `exec` replaces the current process with the new process and **never returns**.  `system` invokes another process and **returns its exit value** to the current process.  Using backticks invokes another process and **returns the output** of that process to the current process.

Answer (score 0):

In my case worked this.

```rb
output = `nmap localhost`
```

This one saves your output to the variable, so the answer is use `` instead of system.