# need to set environment var for a back-ticks command

Tags: ruby, shell, scripting

how to pass an environment variable to a shell command that I execute using `Kernel#system` et al?

say, I want to run

```
%x{git checkout -f}
```

but this command relies on the environment variable `$GIT_WORK_TREE`. how do I set it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to set the variable in Ruby's `ENV` hash prior to calling the sub-shell:

```
ENV['GIT_WORK_TREE'] = 'foo'
`echo $GIT_WORK_TREE`
```

should return "foo".

See the [`ENV[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/ENV.html#method-c-5B-5D-3D) documentation for more information.

---

```
[1] (pry) main: 0> ENV['GIT_WORK_TREE'] = 'foo'
"foo"
[2] (pry) main: 0> `echo $GIT_WORK_TREE`
"foo\n"
```

Comment: This does work, I was about to say the same thing and did a quick check to make sure.

Comment: As a particular but nasty case, note that your platform could remove some environment variables before launching the sub-shell. For example, [macOS clears DYLD_* env vars when forking](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212945/unable-to-set-dyld-fallback-library-path-in-shell-on-osx-10-11-1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Process.spawn`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-spawn) to set the environment:

```
spawn({'GIT_WORK_TREE' => '/foo/bar'}, "git checkout -f")
```

Comment: thanks. I need to run a few more commands after `git`, can I avoid putting them into a `.sh` file? I was hoping to write a ruby shell script, so to speak.

Comment: Ah, from the way you phrased it, I thought you did mean specifically overriding one variable for just one shell command.

Comment: This also works for `system`, but note that different ways of invoking external commands have different properties / side-effects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31572431/328817. So `spawn` and `system` are different to each other and also different to backticks.