# Linux commands in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, command, exec

I wont write some script in Ruby on Linux server. I need statistic from server and I'm a beginner in Ruby.

I have problem with Linux commands, because if I use exec to use Linux command, my program is fallen without error.

```
disks = ["sda", "sdb"]
```

Code:

```
disks.each do |disk|
  puts "disk test start"
  exec "smartctl -a /dev/#{disk} > /tmp/sestavy/#{disk}"
  puts "disk test end"
end
```

Output:

```
[root@banan sestavy]# ruby test.rb
disk test start
[root@banan sestavy]#
```

Thanks
Honza

Comment: You probably want `system()` instead of `exec()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just what `exec` does: it replaces the currently running program with a new one. This is not specific to Ruby, it works the same way in the shell, in C, in pretty much any other environment.

Comment: As usual can you put here more detailed explanations here? always looking for learning something new from you.. :)

Comment: @Priti it is a biding for the exec system calls group from unix. Check [execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) and [fork-exec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork-exec)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `exec`, it replaces the current process with what you want to execute. So it won't return to your Ruby script. See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks) for different methods for shell execution.