# Ruby check if mounted inside an if condition

Tags: ruby

contents of `a.rb` is :

```
if system("mount | grep /boot") != ""
  print "true"  # or do something
else 
  print "false" # or do something else 
end
```

Running this code doesn't print "true" or "false", but prints the output of system call.

```
]$ ruby a.rb 
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
```

What's the right syntax to check the if condition ?

Answer (score 6):

```
if `mount | grep /boot` != ""
  print "true"  # or do something
else 
  print "false" # or do something else 
end
```

Comment: can you explain what's happening with the `system(...)`

Comment: `system` call returns true if command was found and run successfully

Comment: Here is a good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks

Comment: Note that those are backticks around the system command, not single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby, backticks cause the process to fork, which is expensive and slow.  Instead, you could read /etc/mtab and look at the content which prevents forking.

```
if File.read('/etc/mtab').lines.grep(/boot/)[0]
  # not nil, its mounted
else
  # its nil, not mounted
end
```

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what the 0 represents in the array index?

Comment: See the ruby docs for Array#grep.  When you grep an array, you get an array back.  We're using grep to search the array (of lines from /etc/mtab) for "boot".  If its found, it'll exist in the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use system calls, instead you can try this (fromFile path depends of 
 your operating system, in RedHat is /proc/mounts):

```
fromFile='/proc/mounts'
toFind='/boot'
if File.readlines(fromFile).grep(toFind).size > 0
    print "true"  # or do something
else
    print "false" # or do something else 
end
```