# Passenger + Rails running bash commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have Rails app, server is Passenger + nginx.
In my code I'm running Slic3r via `%x[]`. But it doesn't run and doesn't produce any output.
I also print run command there and if I run it in bash or in console it works.
My server is Digitalocean, Ubuntu + I use RVM

**P.S.**: also trying to use remote debug from RubyMine, but it also doesn't work

Comment: should be `%x{}` not [] I think.  You can also used backticks or [system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system)

Comment: According to "The ruby programming language" book and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks question it doesn't matter.

I think there can be problems with users and permissions

Comment: Looks like you're right.

Comment: But system is some different. I'll try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer wa simple:
according to http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/10/18/backtick-system-exec-in-ruby.html I found that backticks doesn't output STDERR so I just added `%x[#{my_command} 2>&1]` to capture it