# execute a shell script inside ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to execute a shell script inside ruby code and return the result. I
am using `Open3` for this.
Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

require 'open3' # require 'open3' in 1.9
AppArgs = Array.new

def get()    
  source = Net::HTTP.get('integration.twosmiles.com', '/status')
  _shellScript = "grep 'commit' status.html"
  fileHtml = File.new("status.html", "w+")
  fileHtml.puts source
  Open3.popen3(_shellScript) do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
    puts stdout
    puts stdin
    puts stderr

  end
end

get()
```

But it prints

```
#<IO:0x00000000a41ca8>
#<IO:0x00000000a41cf8>
#<IO:0x00000000a41c30>
```

I want to get the stings I searched in the `stdout`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use Open3, their [documentation page](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) tells that stdout, stderr, ... are streams:

In your code, you could simply do:

```
puts stdout.read
puts stdin.read
puts stderr.read
```

*Completely off topic, but ensure you have enough checks in there from an IT security point of view, you shouldn't really execute commands that are 'grepped' from the Internet.*

Answer (score 1):

If the output is very short and you want to buffer the entire output into a single string, you can simply use backticks:

```
`#{_shellScript}`
```

You can also redirect all stderr to stdout as follows

```
`#{_shellScript} &2>1`
```

Here's a quick overview of executing via backticks and other alternate methods:

[Ruby, Difference between exec, system and %x() or Backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks)