# What does "shell out" or "shelling out" mean?

Tags: ruby, unix, bundler

As used in these examples, for instance:

> shell out to bundle from inside a command invoked by bundle exec

or

> shell out to a Ruby command that is not part of your current bundle,

http://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html

or

> i'm shelling out to the heroku command in the rake task

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/400

Comment: Thanks for the links.. Long days back I was keep asking what are those meant for.. Now I got some links from you about those.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means executing a subprocess using backticks (as in `` `command` ``), the `system` call, or other similar methods. These execute the process in a sub-shell, hence the name.

You can find a lot more details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18623297/29470

Answer (score 3):

> Spawning a pipeline of connected programs via an intermediate shell —
>   a.k.a. “shelling out”

http://julialang.org/blog/2012/03/shelling-out-sucks/

And the related reddit comment thread: http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1bwbyf/shelling_out_sucks/

So, from what I can gather, I presume it means **"going out from the context of the executing program, to the surrounding program, or execution environment"**, in broad terms. Usually you go out to the unix shell, hence the term *shell out*.