# Running node.js code from Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

I am trying to integrate some node.js code with my Rails application. Basically its a js file with some code that process will keep running in background.

I have followed the following steps:

- Added code in root of rails app in some test_node.js file.
- Now what I do is pass a value to my system using exec function of ruby, e.g exec "node test_node.js".
- This works perfectly fine but it chop my server from processing any requests.
- To pass it to background i tried using nohup e.g: exec "nohup node test_node.js".
- When I run this code my server crashes.

I am Rails developer and never worked on node app so have no idea if I taking it right way or not.

Comment: What server? Did you used `fork and exec`? Can you rewrite test_node.js in ruby?

Comment: I am using Unicorn for my application, its not possible to rewrite  test_node.js in Ruby. I tried using `fork and exec` it worked but as I checked in logs I feel it stopped server and forked it again. Will it work on production as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec` replaces the currently running process with a new one. Thus, to run something in the background you should `fork` and `exec` in the child.

```
fork { exec('node', 'test_node.js', ...) }
```

`nohup` is not needed.

See also [Ruby, Difference between exec, system and %x() or Backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks)

Comment: awesome, is there some way to check the logs of these process?

Comment: You can redirect stdout/stderr to a file right before the exec.