# Sinatra executing ls on sever side

Tags: html, ruby, web-services, sinatra

I am trying to show in Chrome using Sinatra, the result of `ls`. But the explorer gets in an "Connecting..." loop.

My code is:

```
require 'rubygems' if RUBY_VERSION < "1.9"
require 'sinatra/base'

#This is the webservice to launch the gamma project
#Using Request at the principal webpage
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    result = exec "ls"
    puts result 
  end   
end
```

I am not sure of that `puts`, I think that maybe is not the apropiate method. What could be happening and how can I solve it?

PS: In the explorer I used `localhost.com:4567/`

Answer (score 0):

Use the backticks ( *`* ) instead of the Kernel#exec command. The former returns a string that you can then use in your ruby process. The latter throws your execution context into a new process and has no return value.

```
get '/' do
  result = %x`ls`
  puts result
end
```

Note that the call to `puts` will not look very nice and that you'll probably want to format it or parse/manipulate it further. But at least you'll get something you can use.

Answer (score 0):

As [@pgblu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3984518/pgblu) pointed out you should use backticks.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18623297/1279355

And the second thing, `puts` print the result only to your shell/log, 
but to see the result in your chrome you need either:

```
get '/' do
  result = %x`ls`
  return result
end
```

or

```
get '/' do
  result = %x`ls`
  result
end
```

As you can see the return is optional, if there is no return Sinatra just displays the last variable/operation.