# Creating alias on Ruby - Vim output is not to a terminal

Tags: ruby, linux, vim

I am trying to create an alias on Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

if ARGV[0]
  `git add -A && git commit -m #{ARGV[0]} && git push`
else
  `git add -A && EDITOR='TERM=xterm vim' git commit && git push`
end
```

I tried first without `EDITOR...`, but any thing I try I get `Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal`.

What I want is vim to appear when I do not enter any commit message. But instead I get that message.

## Update

I think what I need is to capture editor output as git does. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Backticks capture command output into a string for you to use in your script, which Vim is rightfully unhappy with because it won't be able to print you a UI. Use `system()` instead, which hands everything over to the new process. If you don't need to come back to your Ruby script, you can use `exec()`, which replaces the process entirely.

You're also going to need to quote your message as `git commit -m "#{ARGV[0]}"`, or it will be interpreted as `git commit -m My Commit Message` and complain there are no files `Commit` or `Message`. And then of course, you'll need to escape the message itself so you don't break out of the doublequotes early. Look at [Shellwords#shellescape](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) for that.

Comment: For more information on the differences between `[backtick]` `system()` and `exec()`, take a look at this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks