# Ruby Curl::Easy pass -u parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, curb

I'm using the ruby curb gem and trying to call this api in the code.  But, I'm not sure how to pass the -u parameter.

```
curl -X GET -H 'Accept: application/json' -u 111122223333: https://api.somesite.com/v1/apps/e876c39/users/activities?updated_since=20130925T120000Z
```

Here's the code I have so far, but it doesn't work without the -u option.  I tried adding it as a parameter, but doesn't work.

```
url = "https://api.somesite.com/v1/apps/e876c39/users/activities?updated_since=20130925T120000Z"

curl = Curl::Easy.new(url)
curl.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
curl.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
curl.username = ENV['APP_ID'].to_s + ':'
result = curl.perform
```

Comment: I tried that, but still get the message  
curl.body_str
{"message":"Not authorized"}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to pass both username and password (with the `:` delimiter)  to the `username=` method, but [glancing at the docs](http://curb.rubyforge.org/classes/Curl/Easy.html#M000092) it looks like that method is for setting the username only (not a big surprise). If you want to set both the username and password with the colon syntax, it looks like [`userpwd=`](http://curb.rubyforge.org/classes/Curl/Easy.html#M000016) is the method you want:

> #### `easy.userpwd =` string => string
>
> Set the username/password string to use for subsequent calls to `perform`. The supplied string should have the form `"username:password"`

Comment: I tried that, but still get the message curl.body_str {"message":"Not authorized"}

Comment: What output do you get in stderr if you set `curl.verbose = true`?

Comment: * Connected to api.humanapi.co (54.69.45.169) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.humanapi.co
* Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
* Server certificate: DigiCert Global Root CA
> GET /v1/apps/11111/users/activities?updated_since=20130925T120000Z HTTP/1.1
Host: api.humanapi.co
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

Comment: < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 22:26:17 GMT
< Server: nginx
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Length: 28
< Connection: keep-alive

Comment: I'm not sure where the issue is, sorry. Given that it's SSL, it could be a lot of things.

Comment: The curl command works fine on the command line.  How do you call the curl command in ruby without using curl::easy?

Comment: You can use `system` or `exec`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks

Comment: How do you store the results from the system command to a variable?  I tried result = Kernel.system “curl ...") but the value in result is just true whereas the curl command returned json data.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using RestClient

```
require 'rest_client'    

response = RestClient::Resource.new "https://api.humanapi.co/v1/apps/#{ENV['CLIENT_ID']}/users/activities?updated_since=20130925T120000Z", "#{ENV['APP_ID']}:", ""

results = JSON.parse response.get
```