# Using c++ solution in rails app

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, opencv

I have a C++ project using OpenCV for some operations with images (visual studio 2010; opencv2.4.9). I need make rails app with functions of my project on C++. Moreover I need give some parameters from rails app to C project and take result to rails app.
**How can i do it?** 
P.s.: OpenCV for ruby not suitable for me.

Comment: http://chris911.github.io/blog/2014/08/10/writing-a-ruby-gem-with-c-extension/

Answer (score 0):

You could use backticks, or `%x()` to execute your C++ program. It's just like you would execute it from a terminal, i.e. `%x(/path/to/your/C++/executable parameter1 parameter2)`

For more information on this, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks).

Comment: "Cannot execute binary file"

Comment: Is this the only error output? Can you give more information?

Answer (score 0):

@tschale already mentioned a solution. Here is a more elaborate solution that you would use if your code is expected to be put on the internet or internal network anytime soon.

Get a message queue - redis, beanstalkd, rabbitmq. This is a third executable that you need to run on your web host. This executable provides REST APIs for updating the queue.

If your rails app wants to do a task, it would push a message onto this queue. The message would look something like this:

```
{
    "task": "run_facedetect",
    "param1": "something",
    "param2": {
        "detail1": 45
        ...
    }
}
```

(I'm using JSON only as an example. You're free to use any encoding you want).

The rails app only has to push to queue and it is done.

Now your C/C++ application is listening to the queue (using the REST api). As soon as it sees a message, it spawns a `facedetect` app with the given parameters. Once done, the results are stored in a place where you rails app can read it.