# Run two ruby scripts from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, padrino

So this is a simple rake task:

```
task :map_reduce do
  puts 'Running map reduce scripts...'
  ruby "#{PADRINO_ROOT}/map_reduce/raw_visits_map.rb '03-08-2016' 90" && ruby "#{PADRINO_ROOT}/map_reduce/raw_visits_reducer.rb"
end
```

The first script outputs the result in STDOUT to be further read by the so called 'reducer'.
In the terminal, I am able to run those two scripts like:

```
ruby first_script.rb param1 param2 | ruby second_script.rb
```

So the second script can read from STDOUT like

```
res = ARGF
```

But how can I line up the 2 executions inside that rake task?

How I wrongfully tried it's not working.

Comment: It might be easier to require the ruby class directly into your rake task, but if you want to run a script from a rake task you can run any shell code in Ruby using backticks, like this: `\`ruby first_script.rb param1 param2 | ruby second_script.rb\``

Comment: @omnikron thanks mate, worked like a charm :) write it as an answer and I'll accept it. Cheers!

Comment: done! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to require the ruby class directly into your rake task, but if you want to run a script from a rake task you can run any shell code in Ruby using backticks, like this:

```
`ruby first_script.rb param1 param2 | ruby second_script.rb`
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use backticks or the `%x` syntax.

Also see answers to: [Ruby, Difference between exec, system and %x() or Backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks)