# Bash to Ruby - Obtain a list with whois and grep command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm curious if there's a simple way to convert a bash command into a ruby script.

If you type this in your command line, you'll get a list of ip networks.

```
whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS35995' | grep -Eo "([0-9.]+){4}/[0-9]+"
```

Is there an easy way to do something similar in Ruby, or do I have to manually code that?

Sorry for the noob question and thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could leave the command as is and use @AndreyDeineko's valid solution.

You could execute the grep command inside Ruby with [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
abc   = 'AS35995'
whois = `whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin #{abc}'`
# route:      8.25.194.0/23
# descr:      Twitter
# origin:     AS35995
# admin-c:    NETWO3685-ARIN
# tech-c:     NETWO3685-ARIN
# notify:     noc@twitter.com
# mnt-by:     MAINT-AS13414
# changed:    ck@twitter.com 20121028  #17:03:09Z
# source:     RADB

# route:      8.25.196.0/23
# descr:      Twitter
# origin:     AS35995
# ....

p routes = whois.scan(/[\d\.]{7,}\/\d+/)
#=> ["8.25.194.0/23", "8.25.196.0/23", "192.133.78.0/23", "8.25.194.0/24", "8.25.195.0/24", "8.25.196.0/24", "8.25.197.0/24", "185.45.4.0/24", "103.252.112.0/23", "185.45.4.0/23"]
```

This regex is simple but might match too much. From this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html), it looks like a more accurate regex would be :

```
/\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\/\d+\b/
```

Route is now an array of strings, containing the `route` values from `whois`.

Finally, it seems you could also execute `whois` with this [gem](https://whoisrb.org/).

Comment: nice! thanks! This is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: as usually - perfect, involved answer. +1 to gold ;)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko : Thanks! It has been a good month. My next goal is to be ahead of JonSkeet in [January](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2017-01-01/6419007#6419007) 1 day to go! :)

Comment: Still, I need to answer many questions to get enough points. He has accumulated more than 30000 questions, and he gets 200 points a day even if he's gone fishing.

Comment: Just a quick add for those who want to handle that dynamically: 

@abc = "AS35995"

whois = `whois -h whois.radb.net -- "-i origin #{@abc}"`

Answer (score 2):

Well, [you have quite a few options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18623297/1772830).

Here is a backticks option (symply surround any bash command with backticks):

```
puts `whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS35995' | grep -Eo "([0-9.]+){4}/[0-9]+"`
# 8.25.194.0/23
# 8.25.196.0/23
# 192.133.78.0/23
# 8.25.194.0/24
# 8.25.195.0/24
# 8.25.196.0/24
# 8.25.197.0/24
# 185.45.4.0/24
# 103.252.112.0/23
# 185.45.4.0/23
```

[`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) option:

```
system("whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS35995' | grep -Eo '([0-9.]+){4}/[0-9]+'")
# 8.25.194.0/23
# 8.25.196.0/23
# 192.133.78.0/23
# 8.25.194.0/24
# 8.25.195.0/24
# 8.25.196.0/24
# 8.25.197.0/24
# 185.45.4.0/24
# 103.252.112.0/23
# 185.45.4.0/23
```

Comment: So this would mean that i can't iterate through them, right?

Comment: @Harakiri: You can, if you use `.split` on the string returned by the command.

Comment: hey Andrey kudos to you! I've gone with the answer from Eric.