# Why, in Ruby, backticks and `system()` have different blocking behavior when calling `xdg-open`?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, posix, subshell

Based on the Ruby documentation, both backticks and `system()` have the same blocking behavior (that is, they are both blocking calls).

When I use them to execute a call to `xdg-open` though (which in itself, forks the system process, for example `libreoffice` and exits), backticks blocks while the system process is executing, while `system()` blocks only during the system process invocation.

This is a trivial example:

```
`xdg-open myspreadsheet.ods`        # will block until exiting libreoffice
system 'xdg-open myspreadsheet.ods' # will block until libreoffice is invoked
```

Comment: Probably relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks

Comment: That question doesn't unfortunately mention the difference, blocking-wise, between the two (it's only stated that both are blocking).