# Rails Server dies after calling .exe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, py2exe

I just started to develop a webpage with RoR and when my create method inside my  controller is called and an .exe file created with python and py2exe is executed the server suddenly stops without any exceptions. Can someone tell me why this happens? (The running server is a localhost:3000).

The create method:

```
@cotizador = Cotizador.new(cotizador_params)
if @cotizador.save
  exec("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/forcot/dist/ksnf.exe")
```

The .exe file that I created with python changes .docx files but no log file is generated.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What does your create method do? How does it look like? What does the `exe` file do? How do you call it? How does the log file look like? Please show some code.

Comment: @spickermann is that useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs of [`Kernel#exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec):

> Replaces the current process by running the given external command, [...].

That means your server process is stopped and replaced with the `exe` and therefore your server cannot answer anymore because it simply does run anymore.

Just use [`Kernel#system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) instead:

```
system("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/forcot/dist/ksnf.exe")
```

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18623297/2483313) about various ways do system calls in Ruby and their differences.