# Ruby Regular expression to get percentage from specific line

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following output:

```
Name                              Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------------------------------
src/global_information.py             8      1    88%   6
src/settings.py                      38      0   100%
src/storage_backends.py               4      4     0%   1-5
src/urls.py                           8      0   100%
users/admin.py                        1      0   100%
users/apps.py                         3      3     0%   1-5
users/forms.py                        5      0   100%
users/models.py                       1      0   100%
users/tests/tests_views_urls.py       5      0   100%
users/urls.py                         5      0   100%
users/views.py                        1      1     0%   1
---------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                79      9    89%
```

I need to get the TOTAL percentage, which is 89%. I try the following two regex:

```
TOTAL\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\%
```

and

```
(?<=TOTAL\s).*
```

I can get the correct line but not sure how to extract the percentage part of it. This needs to be achieved in a regular expression due that I don’t have access to any tool

Thanks

Comment: what tools are you using for the job? extract in regex usually use capture group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
TOTAL.*?(\d+)%
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/CDKe3T/1)**

Or if you want to capture the `%` then

```
TOTAL.*?(\d+%)
```

Then grab the content from the capturing group `$1`

Comment: @MarcoHerrarte, have you tried the regex without the parentheses? `TOTAL.*?\d+%`

Answer (score 1):

```
str=<<_
Name                              Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------------------------------
src/global_information.py             8      1    88%   6
src/settings.py                      38      0   100%
src/storage_backends.py               4      4     0%   1-5
src/urls.py                           8      0   100%
users/admin.py                        1      0   100%
users/apps.py                         3      3     0%   1-5
users/forms.py                        5      0   100%
users/models.py                       1      0   100%
users/tests/tests_views_urls.py       5      0   100%
users/urls.py                         5      0   100%
users/views.py                        1      1     0%   1
---------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                79      9    89%
_

str[/^TOTAL.*?\K\d+%/] #=> "89%
```

`\K` means discard everything matched so far. The non-greedy modifier `?` in `.*?` is needed. Without it the match before `\K` would end with the next-to-last digit in the total percentage (here the `"8"` in `"89%"`, the `"3"` in `"1234%"`).

Answer (score 0):

`awk '/TOTAL/{ print $4}' <INPUT_FILE>`

Comment: This certainly provides an `awk` solution but OP needs Ruby's regex solution.

Comment: Please add some explanatory text.

Comment: If you surround your expression with a pair of backticks you can execute it within a Ruby program: `\`awk '/TOTAL/{ print $4}' test\` #=> "89%\n"`. To get rid of the newline add `.chomp` after the ending backtick. The various ways of invoking system programs is discussed in answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks).