# Capture ANSI colorized output with Ruby's Open3 / Process.spawn()

Tags: ruby, ansi-escape

I'm using the `sass-lint` NPM package to style-check `.scss` files from within a Rake task, thus:

```
  sass_lint_cmd = "sass-lint --config #{ui_library_path}/scss/.sass-lint.yml '#{ui_library_path}/scss/*.scss' -v -q --max-warnings=0"
  output, status = Open3.capture2e(sass_lint_cmd)
  raise IOError, output unless status == 0
```

This basically works, insofar as in the event of any linter warnings or errors the Rake task aborts and the `sass-lint` output, including errors, is dumped to the console.

However, when run directly, `sass-lint` produces nice colorized output. When captured by `capture2e`, the colors are lost.

I assume the issue is that `sass-lint` (or Node) detects it's not running in a TTY, and so outputs plain text. Is there some `Process.spawn()` option I can pass to `Open3.capture2e()`, or some other method, by which I can make it think it's running in a TTY?

(Note: I did look at [Trick an application into thinking its stdout is a terminal, not a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdout-is-a-terminal-not-a-pipe), but the BSD version of `script` that ships with macOS doesn't seem to support either the `--return` or the `-c` options, and I'm running on macOS.)

---

**Update:** I tried `script -q /dev/null` and `PTY.spawn()` as per [Piccolo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51528315/27358), but no luck.

`script -q /dev/null …` works from the command line, but doesn't work in `Open3.capture2e()` (it runs, but produces monochrome output and a spurious `Bundler::GemNotFound` stack trace).

As for `PTY.spawn()`, replacing the code above with the following:

```
r, _w, pid = PTY.spawn(scss_lint_command)
_, proc_status = Process.wait2(pid)
output, status = [r, proc_status.exitstatus]
(warn(output); raise) unless status == 0
```

the subprocess never seems to complete; if I `ps` in another terminal it shows as in interruptible sleep status. Killing the subprocess doesn't free up the parent process.

The same happens with the block form.

```
output, status = nil
PTY.spawn(scss_lint_command) do |r, _w, pid|
  _, proc_status = Process.wait2(pid)
  output, status = [r, proc_status.exitstatus]
end
(warn(output); raise) unless status == 0
```

Comment: Does the `script -q ...` thing work from the command line if you pipe it into `cat`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Ruby's excellent [`pty`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html) library instead of `Open3`?

Pseudo terminals, per [the thread you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1401557/1743874), seem to emulate an actual TTY, so the script wouldn't know it wasn't in a terminal unless it checked for things like `$TERM`, but that can also be spoofed with relative ease.

According to [this flowchart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31572431/1743874), the downside of using `pty` instead of `Open3` is that `STDERR` does not get its own stream.

---

Alternatively, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13587964/1743874), also from the thread you linked, `script -q /dev/null $COMMAND` appears to do the trick on Mac OS X.

On Macs, `ls -G` colorizes the output of `ls`, and as a brief test, I piped `ls -G` into `cat` as follows:

```
script -q /dev/null ls -G | cat
```

and it displayed with colors, whereas simply running

```
ls -G | cat
```

did not.

This method also worked in `irb`, again using `ls -G`:

```
$ touch regular_file
$ touch executable_file
$ mkdir directory
$ chmod +x executable_file
$ irb
2.4.1 :001 > require 'Open3'
 => true
2.4.1 :002 > output, status = Open3.capture2e("ls -G")
 => ["directory\nexecutable_file\nregular_file\n", #<Process::Status: pid 39299 exit 0>]
2.4.1 :003 > output, status = Open3.capture2e("script -q /dev/null ls -G")
 => ["^D\b\b\e[1m\e[36mdirectory\e[39;49m\e[0m       \e[31mexecutable_file\e[39;49m\e[0m regular_file\r\n", #<Process::Status: pid 39301 exit 0>]
2.4.1 :004 >
```

Comment: Tried both, no luck. :( See update. But I'm probably not calling `PTY.spawn()` / `Process.wait2()` correctly.

Comment: @DavidMoles Hmm, not sure about the `script -q /dev/null ...` not working, but let me see if I can figure out what's wrong with your `PTY.spawn()`ing.

Comment: @DavidMoles I tried running the following:
`lines = []; PTY.spawn("ls -G && sleep 5") {|reader, writer, pid| reader.each {|line| lines << line }; Process.wait2(pid) }`, and `Process.wait2(pid)` blocked for the right amount of time, and the output was correct. I don't really see any difference between what you did and that; can you try running mine on your system so we can see if it's a difference between `ls -G` and your command, or if it's a system issue?