# Testing validity of database seed file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Seed files can become invalid fast as code grows. I just had a situation where the open merge request had all tests running and passing but when I run `rails db:seed`  on staging server failed as the seed file did not have all the required fields for that particular model.
Is there a way we can always test for validity of the seed file?

Maybe relevant:

- I am using gitlab CI for running CI and deployment
- rails version - 5.2
- rspec version 3

Comment: You could write a simple spec that runs `rails db:seed` and write expectations about the return value and maybe the database mutations that occur.

Comment: How do you run `rails db:seed ` from within rspec tests? I am aware of using FactoryBot but not seed files

Comment: `expect(system("rails db:seed")).to be_truthy` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks for plenty of other options on how to run it.

Comment: There are also more fancy ways of testing rake tasks (`"rails db:seed"` is really just an alias of "rake db:seed"). https://robots.thoughtbot.com/test-rake-tasks-like-a-boss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a separate CI task that runs `rails db:seed`, next to your existing one that runs `rspec` (or `rails spec`, or whatever spelling it uses).

Comment: Will it stop the the pipeline from moving to the next step if it fails?

Comment: Yes, if it encounters an exception, ruby will exit with a non-zero status, which CI will treat as a failure

Comment: Okay, let me run a parallel job together with `rspec` an see if it passes

Comment: This works, I added a parallel job and now it does not deploy if seeding fails

Answer (score 2):

Turns out its actually dead simple to test with RSpec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "db:seed" do
  it "works" do
    expect { Rails.application.load_seed }.to_not raise_error
  end
  it "creates a foo" do
    expect { Rails.application.load_seed }.to change(Foo, :count)
  end
end
```

Which can kind of be expected since "seeding" really just involves requiring a single ruby file.

[`Rails.application.load_seed`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6a728491b66340345a91264b5983ad81944ab97a/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L549) is used by the `rake db:seed` task (aka `rails db:seed` in Rails 5+).

Comment: This assumes you´re using `database_cleaner` to clean up.

Comment: it would be nice to have a way to clean seed records after testing seeds, similarly to what Rspec `use_transactional_fixtures` does.