# How to execute .sh file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sh

I'm trying to execute .sh file in rails index action.

I try `exec"sh app/controllers/file.sh"`
it's execute it in terminal then stop the server! I don't know why.
And I try `output = system"sh app/controllers/file.sh"` it's return true in the browser not what is in the .sh file

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [`Open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) class, specifically [`capture2`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture2) or [`capture3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3):

```
require 'open3'
stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3("sh app/controllers/myscript.sh")
```

As you can see above `capture3` will get you the `stdout`, `stderr`, and `status` of your script run. While `capture2` will just return `stdout` and `status`. There are other useful functions in `Open3` which are worth looking at.

To understand why `exec` and `system` are behaving the way they are, you can read this SO answer: [Ruby, Difference between exec, system and %x() or Backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18623297/33226)