# Get nginx version in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to obtain the current version of `nginx` in Ruby.  I've tried all of these, and nothing seems to work:

```
a = `nginx -v`
puts a             # ==> nil
a = `nginx -V`
puts a             # ==> nil again
a = system('nginx -v')
puts a             # ==> nil
```

Anybody know how I can obtain this data?  Strange behaviour.  Same for `postgres` and `ruby` work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a handful of methods that can run system commands and all of them are working differently. For example `` `date` `` works different than `system('date')`. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks).

Also, some commands write to `STDOUT`, some to `STDERR` and, apparently `nginx -v` writes to `STDERR`. For this scenario there's another option which gives access to more info: [Open3](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Open3.html)

```
require 'open3'
stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3("nginx -v")
# ["", "nginx version: nginx/1.21.6\n", #<Process::Status: pid 22253 exit 0>] 

stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3("date")
# ["Sun Jan 30 12:55:29 EET 2022\n", "", #<Process::Status: pid 22264 exit 0>]

stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3("ruby -v")
["ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [arm64-darwin21]\n", "", #<Process::Status: pid 22571 exit 0>]
```

Comment: OK, I have that in my arsenal.  Even so, if the `CLI` (`zsh`) shows that output, would it not be returned to the `method` for the first two?

Comment: You are right, the output will not be returned to the variable even if you see it in the terminal.