# Turning on a specific program at a specific time and turning off the computer at another specific time

Tags: ruby

I decided to write a program in RUBY in which the following things should be done:

1 - this program must  run a specific program (for example utorrent) at a specific time (for example 1 pm).
2 - this program  must turn off my computer at another specific time.

I don't have any idea about the algorithm and manner of writing such program.

Comment: Please specify what operating system you are going to be using - or is it meant to be portable?

Comment: My operating system is Windows7 but if it can be potable , it's very good!.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to do this is to simply send kill signals to the processes, requesting the app shut down normally (Linux), or in Windows [use taskkill](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/446/xp_kill_windows_process_command_line_taskkill/).

To shutdown a machine in Windows, you can use `shutdown /s /f` which forcibly closes any programs that are running, and turns the computer off.

No matter which way you do it, you'll basically be running the [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby)system() command in Ruby, which runs command line commands. To make your app portable, you simply look up how to do these tasks in each target OS, and you're done.

Two more alternatives that work the same as your Ruby proposal, but which are not as easily portable:

- Write a batch file in Windows that calls `taskkill`, or a bash script on Linux. Unless the program in question provides a specific way to shut it down via its own command-line parameters, this should work for any/all applications.
- You can also use `Task Scheduler` in Windows, or `cron` in Linux to do the same thing.