# How do I get linux system information in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, fedora, system-information

How do I get the software/hardware information of a linux system (this has to work for Fedora, Ubuntu etc) in Ruby?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The wonderful people behind Chef, have an excellent gem called Ohai https://github.com/opscode/ohai that returns system info such as OS, kernel, specs, fqdn, disks, space, memory, users, interfaces, ssh keys etc. as a hash. It is quite complete and very good. It also installs a command line binary (also called ohai).

Answer (score 6):

You could try the [sysinfo](http://sysinfo.rubyforge.org/) gem. If that doesn't work you might be able to [try making a system call, parse the output,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby) and then call the relevant command to get further information.

For example, on OS X, `uname -a` gives me the following output, which then allows me to know what other distro-specific commands are likely available.

```
$ uname -a
Darwin [machine-name].local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: For that `uname -s` is often sufficient (or `RUBY_PLATFORM` inside Ruby) :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could try the [sys-uname](https://github.com/djberg96/sys-uname) gem, which provides some access to OS information. That guy also has a few other gems for other system info, like cpu, user groups, etc.