# How To get hardware information using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, hardware

I'm trying to get the hardware information of my server and save it to database, How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want do that? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: FWIW: this answer has some linux-specific suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882664/how-do-i-get-linux-system-information-in-ruby

Comment: @endyey-es if those answers bellow work for you please consider accept one. This will help others to see the best answer to this question, and will pay for responder's time and efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it depends on your system, but looks like there is a gem called [hardware_information](https://rubygems.org/gems/hardware_information/versions/1.0.3). Maybe it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is running Linux, your code can just read files in /proc to get hardware information. 
For example:

1. File /proc/meminfo contains the ram information.
2. File /proc/cpuinfo contains the cpu information.
3. There are many other files.