# How do I get the command output from the Albacore exec task?

Tags: ruby, rake, albacore

Is there a way to get the command output of the exec task?

```
exec :checkout do |cmd|
  cmd.command = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/tf.exe'    
  cmd.parameters 'checkout'
end
```

Comment: Do you mean the output of the command or the return code?

Comment: You definitely mean the console output and not the exit code? Because `tf.exe checkout` doesn't produce anything interesting ("No files specified"). Could you say what you want to do with this output so I can help (I maintain Albacore).

Comment: And how do you want to "get" it? Capture it in a variable? Because `system()` puts it on the console already. If you just need it visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned albacore and you use the task `exec`. If there is no special need of albacore you may use standard ruby tools:

```
#Define the command:
cmd = 'dir'
#or in your case:
#cmd ['"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe"',
#        'checkout'].join(' ')


#Version one:
output = `#{cmd}`
puts output

#Version two:
output = %x{#{cmd}}
puts output
```

More solutions may be found at [Getting output of system() calls in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby)