# How to use Unix pager programs like `less` from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unix

Suppose I have a string called `very_long_string` whose content I want to send to the standard output. But since the string is very long, I want to use `less` to display the text on the terminal. When I use

```
`less #{very_long_string}`
```

I get `File not found` error message, and if I use:

```
`less <<< #{very_long_string}`
```

I get `unexpected redirection` error message.

So, how to use `less` from inside Ruby?

Comment: Have you tried `long_string | less` ?

Comment: @alex How to do so from inside ruby? But thanks I can try `\`echo #{long_string}|less\``.

Comment: @alex And that too doesn't seem to work, I still get file not found error message

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could open a pipe and feed your string to less via its stdin.

```
IO.popen("less", "w") { |f| f.puts very_long_string }
```

(Assuming very_long_string is the variable holding your string.)

See: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/IO.html#method-c-popen

Comment: There is more to this than meets the eye.  Two issues I have: 1) hitting 'q' to quit less produces an EPIPE error that results in a nasty looking stack being dumped out.  That's easy to catch wit a rescue.  2) hitting ^C before all the output has been sent to less.  less basically just eats the ^C.  The ruby code does get an Interrupt but I can't figure out how to gracefully exit and still have less also exit gracefully and set the TTY back to their original settings.

Answer (score 1):

Although `less` can read text files its natural fit is to use it as the last command in a pipe. So a natural fit would be:

```
shell-command-1 | shell-command-2 | shell-command-3 | less
```

At your shell prompt:

```
echo tanto va la gatta al lardo che ci lascia lo zampino|less
```

..So you can try this in irb:

```
`echo tanto va la gatta al lardo che ci lascia lo zampino|less`
```

but I will prefer to use:

```
your_string = "tanto va la gatta al lardo che ci lascia lo zampino"
`echo "#{your_string}"|less`
```

If you have time read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby) SO question.

For a thorough demonstration of using system calls in ruby see this gist:
https://gist.github.com/4069

Comment: I actually did use it, but nothing happened. No errors, no display nothing. The script simply returned. However, IO.popen() as suggested by @user1252434 worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

A simple hack:

```
require 'tempfile'
f = Tempfile.new('less')
f.write(long_string)

system("less #{f.path}")
```