# Store average time from ping command in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, networking, ping

I have written the following system command to ping a website which gives me desired ICMP response.

```
response = system("ping -c1 www.stackoverflow.com")
```

The response is as--

```
PING stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=1 ttl=52 time=336 ms

--- stackoverflow.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 336.699/336.699/336.699/0.000 ms
 => true
```

Now i want to store the average time from the above statistics. So i hit the next system command which is as.

```
response_time = system("ping -c 1 www.pintile.com | tail -1| awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2")
```

This gives me the average time but does not store it in the response_time variable. Tha value stored in response_time is **true**.

```
335.898
 => true
```

Now my question is **How to store the average time in the response_time variable??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use curl :

```
curl -w '\nLookup time:\t%{time_namelookup}\nConnect time:\t%{time_connect}\nPreXfer time:\t%{time_pretransfer}\nStartXfer time:\t%{time_starttransfer}\n\nTotal time:\t%{time_total}\n' -o /dev/null -s http://www.pintile.com
```

you will get the output like :

```
Lookup time:    0.589
Connect time:   0.603
PreXfer time:   0.603
StartXfer time: 1.425

Total time: 2.073
```

hope that help .

**EDITED :**

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1563625/84631).

If you surround your command with backticks, then you don't need to (explicitly) call system() at all.

Use it like :

```
response_time = `ping -c 1 www.pintile.com | tail -1| awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2`
```

Now you will get response_time . :)

Comment: No doubt it gives me the same output but when i run the same using system command in rails console it does not store the value as i mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
`ping -c1 www.stackoverflow.com` =~ %r[= \d+\.\d+/(\d+\.\d+)]
response_time = $1 and $1.to_f
```