# Is there a way to grab a screen session name in irb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gnu-screen, irb

If I login to a remote machine, establish a screen session with `screen -s name`, switch to another user account, and login to a Rails 2 console, is there a way to grab the screen session name in Ruby, for logging purposes?

Comment: Are you okay with doing it at the system level (i.e., shelling out from irb)?  IOW, do you have a way of getting the screen session name from a system command?

Answer (score 0):

If you can obtain the screen session name from the underlying OS, then in Ruby you can always execute a command by using backticks or the `system` call.  See "[Getting output of system() calls in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby)" for more details.

EDIT:

BTW, be sure to see [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5970819/492404).