# Ruby system method arguments

Tags: ruby

I'm quite confused reading the doc of Ruby's `system` method [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system). I'm not sure what are commands and what are options. What do I do if I want to execute the following?

```
wget -pk -nd -P /public/google www.google.com
```

For security reasons, I'd like to use one of the versions that uses no shell (the second and third forms in the URL I gave, rather than the first)

Comment: You could use backticks.

Comment: `file = system(wget -pk -nd -P /public/google www.google.com)`. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby

Comment: Sorry, edited to clarify what I meant.

Comment: @alex: But backticks are subject to the same shell problems that `system("string")` is.

Comment: @nicooga: The problem with `system(string)` is that something unpleasant could be in `string`. Consider what would happen if you have `x = 'www.google.com; rm -rf /some/important/directory'` and then you say `system("wget ... #{x}")`; **don't do it**, think about it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider the examples:

```
system("echo *")
system("echo", "*")
```

The first one passes the string `'echo *'` to the shell to be parsed and executed; that's why `system('echo *')` produces the same output as saying `echo *` from the shell prompt: you get a list of files in the current directory. The corresponding argument form is:

```
commandline : command line string which is passed to the standard shell
```

The second one bypasses the shell entirely. It will look for `echo` in the `PATH` and then execute it with the string `'*'` as its argument. Since the shell expands wildcards (at least on unixy systems), the `*` will stay as a simple `*` and you'll see `*` as the output. The corresponding argument form here is:

```
cmdname, arg1, ... : command name and one or more arguments (no shell)
```

The third form:

```
[cmdname, argv0], arg1, ... : command name, argv[0] and zero or more arguments (no shell)
```

is used when you want to execute `cmdname` but have it show up with a different name in `ps` listings and such. You can see this in action by opening two terminals. Open up `irb` in one of them and say:

```
system('sleep', '10')
```

then quickly switch to the other and look at the `ps` listing. You should see `sleep 10` in there. But, if you give this to `irb`:

```
system(['sleep', 'pancakes'], '10')
```

and check the `ps` listing, you'll see `pancakes 10`. Similar two-terminal tricks will show you a `shell -c sleep 10` if you say `system('sleep 10')`.

If you supply a Hash as the first argument, then that Hash is used as the environment variables for the spawned process. If you supply a Hash as the final argument, then that Hash is used as options; further documentation on the arguments is, as noted in the `system` documentation, available under [`Kernel#spawn`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn).

Comment: Thanks for your long answer! What I'm still not entirely sure is, what counts as an "argument"? Does `-pk`, `-nd`, `-P`, `/public/google`, `www.google.com` each count as one argument?

Comment: @MikaH.: Yes, each of those are arguments.