# delayed_job - handling job return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, exit-code

I am using delayed_job to perform a system call. This system call invokes a Groovy script.

```
class Job
    def perform
        command "groovy file.groovy"
        system command
    end

    def success(job)
        # handle success
    end

    def error(job, exception)
        # handle error, exception
    end
end
```

This is all working perfectly but I always get back a "success" status since my groovy always exits correctly. I am currently throwing `RuntimeExeptions` in the Groovy Script to provoke failing job. When I call `system "groovy progra.groovy"` and it raises an exception (The groovy program raises an Exception), the return value of `system` call is, as expected `false`. But when doing the same via delayed_job, it never accesses the `def error` method but the `def success` method.

Do you have any advise on how delayed_job actually controls the returns of the `perform` method? When does it enter the `error` or `failure` hook. Unfortunately I have not found anything on this topic in the documentation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like this :

```
def perform
    command = "groovy file.groovy"
    system command || raise "Error executing command : #{command}"
end
```

I'm pretty sure delayed_job wraps the perform call in a rescue block and call success or error based on any exception it catches.

Comment: Unfortunately, the system command does not raise any exception. Even when the exit code is 1+ ...

Comment: this is precisely the reason why I suggest you to add '|| raise "Error executing command : #{command}"' after the system() call.

You could also check if the result is nil and in that case raise an Exception like "command #{command} failed (reason : $?)", my first proposition was just a check for "falsy" values

Comment: In combination with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby), I got my error handling running. Thank you a lot.