# Handling PostgreSQL Creating Tables, Associations, and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, associations, pgadmin

Long story short I decided to wipe out my database on my localhost and experiment with posgreSQL and pgAdmin with my Rails app. I first deleted any servers I had via pgAdmin. I then ran `db:create:all`, `db:migrate`, and finally `db:test:prepare`. Now whenever I run my previous spec tests before I did all this database experimentation the majority of my tests fails giving me this error..

```
 Failure/Error: @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password_reset_sent_at' for #<User:0xb48a55c>
```

or

```
 Failure/Error: @user.save
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password_reset_sent_at' for #<User:0xaa9c040>
```

I thought I may have not allowed `password_reset_sent_at` as a non-accessible attribute but it is accessible and my user model has the `has_one :user_reset_password, :dependent => :destroy`.

My database.yml looks like...

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: template_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: jason
  password: password

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: template_test
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: jason
  password: password
```

When I run the application and I create a new user I get this error.

```
undefined method `password_reset_sent_at' for #<User:0xa6fb184>

app/models/user.rb:78:in `empty_password_reset_token'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `create'
```

The `empty_password_reset_token` method is

```
def empty_password_reset_token
  if self.password_digest_changed?
    if self.password_reset_sent_at && self.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
      false
    else
      self.password_reset_token = ""
      self.password_reset_sent_at = ""
    end
  end
end
```

My schema file

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130124193639) do

  create_table "user_login_failures", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "login_failure_attempts"
    t.datetime "created_at",             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             :null => false
  end

  create_table "user_reset_passwords", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "password_reset_token"
    t.datetime "password_reset_sent_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             :null => false
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.string   "password_digest"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true

end
```

I really have no idea why this is not working. The tables all have the appropriate columns and nothing is missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the application work, or is that crashing too?

Comment: The application works fine. Whenever I create a user though, I get a similar error to that of what my rspec tests are returning.

Comment: And you've checked that there is a `password_reset_sent_at` column on your users table?  That's the only thing that's coming to mind right now.

Comment: Correct. I ran both `annotate` a gem and checked the database via `rails db` and it shows that `password_reset_sent_at` is in the table.

Comment: Can you post your `schema.rb` file?

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look at db/schema.rb. Each time you run your tests, the DB is torn down and rebuilt based on the contents of that file. I suspect that according to db/schema.rb, your "users" table does not have a "password_reset_sent_at" column

Comment: I updated my question with my `schema.rb`. Because I have an association between my user and my `password_reset_sent_at`, technically the user table doesn't have it, but the associated one with it does.

Answer (score 0):

Since the columns you're using in the user mode is in another model, you have to call that model first, you have to change `password_reset_token` to

```
def empty_password_reset_token
  if self.password_digest_changed?
    build_user_reset_password unless user_reset_password
    if user_reset_password.password_reset_sent_at && user_reset_password.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
      false
    else
      user_reset_password.password_reset_token = ""
      user_reset_password.password_reset_sent_at = ""
    end
  end
end
```

or you can use delegate and keep the method as is

```
delegate :password_reset_sent_at, :password_reset_token, to: :user_reset_password
```

Comment: Can you further explain what's going on with your code. How does the method know which user `password_resent_sent_at` to delete if the password digest changed?

Answer (score 0):

This may be completely unrelated (I have NO Ruby experience), but I see a lot of 'backticks' (`) in your question.

In various languages, the back tick operator will try to execute a executable on the command line.

MySQL uses backticks for quoting column-names so if you're migrating from MySQL they may be leftovers from MySQL SQL statements

Therefore Ruby may try to execute

```
`password_reset_sent_at'
```

As a system command

[update]
According to this answer, Ruby on Rails seems to use backticks for system access as well:
[Getting output of system() calls in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby)

Please ignore if this is *not* the case, just trying to help out :)

Comment: Thanks for the try and the info. Unfortunately, this is not the problem.