# Ruby - How to run rails console commands inside ruby file?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to create a ruby script that can execute rails commands?

Like:

rails_start.rb:

```
Class RailsStart
    #Start rails server
    rails server
end
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always shell out.

```
system('rails server')
```

or

```
`rails server` # backticks
```

Comment: Is it possible to define path to rails? So you can fire up multiple rails servers for apps. And where did you find this documentation for system?

Comment: It's [Kernel#system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system). No, you can't fire multiple servers this way. Unless you fork or multi-thread. See also [Dir#chdir](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-chdir)

Comment: :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to put backticks around the command:

```
`rails server`
```

But what are you trying to do?