# How would I modify this rake task to start a thin server with support for local debugging?

Tags: ruby, debugging, sinatra, rake

### Question

I want to be able to debug my Sinatra website hosted by Thin on my local machine, and I want to be able to initiate this by using `rake`.

*I'm not able to accept answers suggesting the use of different technologies (e.g. Windows, Rails, Java) or other servers (e.g. unicorn, passenger, puma); however, if what I'm asking for is impossible, then I will accept that answer.*

### What I've tried

My current `Rakefile` contains a task `:start` which starts the Thin server, but when it hits the breakpoint no output is displayed on my terminal.  If I start Thin directly from the terminal, then I see the `(rdb:1)` prompt when it hits the breakpoint as expected.  In either case, the Thin server is correctly running the site (confirmed by commenting out the breakpoint).

#### Gemfile

```
source :rubygems
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
gem 'debugger-pry'
```

#### Rakefile

```
task :start do
  conf = File.expand_path('config.ru', File.dirname(__FILE__))
  `thin -e development -R #{conf} --debug start`
end
```

#### config.ru

```
require File.expand_path('app', File.dirname(__FILE__))

run ModularExample::App.new
```

#### app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'debugger/pry'

module ModularExample
  class App < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do
      debugger
      "Hello, world"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not outputting to STDOUT. The backticks execute the command and return the output as a string so you could do something like

```
puts `thin -e development -R #{conf} --debug start`
```

but you want to stream the processes output to STDOUT so you actually want to do:

```
task :start do
  conf = File.expand_path('config.ru', File.dirname(__FILE__))
  exec("thin -e development -R #{conf} --debug start")
end
```

Learn more about calling command line calls from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby/690174#690174).

Comment: since you don't need the rake environment after starting the server, `exec` would work as well