# save FFMPEG screenshot output file to variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, carrierwave

How can i get the output file of this FFMPEG code saved to a variable?

```
  def take_screenshot
    logger.debug "Trying to grab a screenshot from #{self.file}"
    system "ffmpeg -i #{self.file} -ss 00:00:02 -vframes 1 #{Rails.root}/public/uploads/tmp/screenshots/#{File.basename(self.file)}.jpg"
    self.save!
  end
```

I have tried:
`self.screenshot = system "ffmpeg -i #{self.file} -ss 00:00:02 -vframes 1 #{Rails.root}/public/uploads/tmp/screenshots/#{File.basename(self.file)}.jpg"`

but this doesn't save anything.

thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you want the contents of the jpeg in a variable?  You can capture the stdout of a process in this case, ffmpeg into a variable. The file that ffmpeg writes into is not on stdout.

Comment: Hi av501, I would to save the contents of the jpeg which ffmpeg produces to a variable so I can use this with carrierwave to upload to s3. Will stdout do this?

Comment: See @slhck's answer below. It is correct. Set it to dump to stdout and then use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ffmpeg` usually outputs nothing on stdout and all of its debug messages on stderr. You can make it output the video (or image) to stdout when you pass `-` as the output file. You'd then also need to suppress stderr.

```
system "ffmpeg -i #{self.file} -ss 00:00:02 -c:v mjpeg -f mjpeg -vframes 1 - 2>/dev/null"
```

This will output the raw data of the JPEG-encoded image to stdout. From there you can save the data to a variable and, for example, transfer it somewhere else.

To get stdout from `system` calls, see here: [Getting output of system() calls in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby) – especially [`popen3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) should help you in that case, where you could discard the stderr from within Ruby.