# Ruby Back Tick Cmd line call with variable

Tags: ruby

How can I make calls to the command line using the back tick and variables? Something like:

```
myvar = "C:\Program Files"
`cd ` + myvar
```

Comment: Have you tried `\`cd #{myvar}\``?

Comment: Just a note, but in this specific case you could alteratively use `Dir.chdir(myvar)`

Comment: I agree with the mods, that even a casual google search reveals the answer.  ***Admittedly, none of those answer are as attractively-styled to read as StackOverflow ;)***

Comment: Also, welcome to StackOverflow, @MatthewGreenfield

Answer (score 4):

Also, consider using a `system()` call, for clarity.  Backticks are for short commands.

`system` allows for a *visually-more-obvious* open + close block formatting that befits large, or multi-line OS instructions.

[See this SO Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/690151/263858)

---

Though, if you're writing large OS scripts, put them in a shell file, check it into VCS, and exec that with a ruby one-liner.

Comment: Strange answer. You suggest `system`, but the accepted answer in that link says you should use backticks instead of `system`.

Comment: @Mischa read it closer; it does not say to use backticks '*instead*' – it says that you *don't need to* call `system`.  Which is true.  But system allows for a *visually-more-obvious* open + close block formatting that befits large, or multi-line OS instructions.

Comment: I agree with your point that it's visually more obvious, but that link does not seem to be supporting or expanding on what you say. Although the topic is similar, it seems unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
`cd "#{myvar}"`
```

Example:

```
$ irb --simple-prompt
>> `pwd`
=> "/home/kirti\n"
>> var = 'ruby'
=> "ruby"
>> `cd "#{var}" && pwd`
=> "/home/kirti/ruby\n"
```