# %x for bash scripting returns empty string instead of the actual result

Tags: ruby

```
value = %x( #{"svn lock #{@path}/#{@file}"} )
```

> =>

```
svn: warning: W160035: Path '/README.txt' is already locked by user 'tester' in filesystem 'some_path'
""
```

Returns empty string rather then the svn:warning message. I want to record the svn warning message. What am I doing wrong.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby/20001569#20001569 - You need to use http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture2e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely because the output is being sent to STDERR, not STDOUT (which is all `%x` captures). Because you’re not capturing it, it does what it would normally and prints to the console.

You can either redirect STDERR to STDOUT in your command:

```
%x(svn lock #{@path}/#{@file} 2>&1)
```

Or use [Open3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) to capture both STDOUT & STDERR:

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3("svn lock #{@path}/#{@file}") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  puts "stdout is:" + stdout.read
  puts "stderr is:" + stderr.read
end
```

The first option offloads the work to the shell executing the command and depending on the environment it may not support it. As such using Open3 is a much more portable solution.

Some additional notes: note I’ve removed the unnecessary interpolation in your `%x` statement. Also, consider using [ShellWords](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) to properly escape interpolated string in shell commands. This is particularly important if these are user-inputted strings.

Comment: That's interesting - `%x(svn lock #{@path}/#{@file} 2>&1)`. What does `2>&1` mean ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit It redirects STDERR (which is file descriptor #2) to STDOUT (which is file descriptor #1).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall What is that `&` there ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit The `&` specifies that you’re giving a file descriptor (`1`) as the location to redirect output to. If you didn’t give it then it would send the output to a file named `1`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit No problem. Also note, of course, that that style of output redirection is not done by Ruby but rather by the shell running the command; whereas with Open3 Ruby coordinates the redirection (and is thus more portable).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Just a minor note: the `2>&1` trick won't work on csh compatible shells.

Comment: @toro2k Right. I suppose I should move the note about portability from my comment to the answer… I have been bitten by that before when running a different platform.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yes... That was my 3rd question, but before me you answered.. Again thanks for this.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that backticks (or `%x`) returns the output of STDOUT, whereas in this case you want STDERR. Use e.g. `Open3::capture2e` instead:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture2e