# Run Shell Script from Ruby File and Capture the Output

Tags: ruby, shell, command, output

I would like to run a shell script from my ruby file. Then capture its output and analyze it.

This is the scenario:
- Within my ruby script I need to execute the my_script.sh 
- The shell script produce the followinf output in the terminal

```
> my_script.sh
  xxxxx 1111
  yyyyy 2222
  zzzzz 3333
```

- I need to capture and analyse this ouput inside the ruby script in order to find if a keyword is displayed (e.g., yyyy).

I'm using the following comand:

```
my_script = "/home/script.sh"
system("sh #{my_script}")
```

I'm not able to capture the output produced in the terminal for parsing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `system`, it does not capture STDOUT. Use backticks (or `%x()`):

```
output = %x( #{my_script} )
```