# Run a process, capture its output and exit code

Tags: ruby

I know how to run an external process as there are many ways to do so. But how do I capture its output **and** exit code to the variables? These, the most popular ways of running a process, don't work as I want:

```
a = `ls -l` # "a" captures only output
b = system "ls -l " # "b" captures only exit code
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting output of system() calls in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby)

Comment: @halfelf, is what sense it is a duplicate?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a way to get this out.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'open3'

Open3.popen3("ls -l") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  puts stdout.read
  puts wait_thr.value.exitstatus 
end

# >> total 52
# >> -rw-r--r-- 1 arup users    0 Aug  5 09:32 a.rb
# >> drwxr-xr-x 2 arup users 4096 Jul 20 20:37 FSS
# >> drwxr-xr-x 2 arup users 4096 Jul 20 20:37 fss_dir
# >> -rw-r--r-- 1 arup users   42 Jul 19 01:36 out.txt
# .....
#...
# >> 0
```

Doco is very clear of [`::popen3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3). `stdout` gives [`IO`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html) object. So, we need to use [`IO#read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-read) method. And `wait_thr.value` gives us [`Process::Status`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Process/Status.html). Now once we have that object, we can use [`#exitstatus`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Process/Status.html#method-i-exitstatus) method for the same.

Comment: why don't use use "do" for the multiline block?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Copy paste..err.. :-) pardon me

Comment: how do I retrieve the error (Exception) from stderr?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Didn't get you. You want `Exception` class name ? Yes `stderr` will give you the error message as a *string*.

Comment: I want exception as an instance of class Exception to be able to re-raise it, not just a string.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp The approach I have shown, with that it is not possible. It will give you the *message* . Probably, you can ask a diff question. May be others can you help you on it. I don't have the answer ..Sorry :(

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, *I want exception as an instance of class Exception to be able to re-raise it*.  See my additional answer.

Answer (score 5):

Most appropriate is to read `$?.exitstatus`:

```
a = `ls -l`        # gets output
b = $?.exitstatus  # gets exit code
```

Test:

```
`true`
# => ""
$?.exitstatus
# => 0
`false`
# => ""
$?.exitstatus
# => 1
$?.class
# => Process::Status
```

See [Process::Status](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Process/Status.html) for more ways to handle exit status.

Comment: Nice. +1.......And if you don't like the perl-like variable names(who does?!!), you can write: `require 'english'` and `puts $CHILD_STATUS.exitstatus`

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at the [popen4 gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/popen4), as it will allow you to get stout/stderr and the exit status.

Also see this page describing [6 Ways to Run Shell Commands in Ruby](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html) which also details popen4 usage.

```
status = Open4::popen4("false") do |pid, stdin, stdout, stderr|
    puts "stdout: #{stdout}" 
end
puts status
```

Comment: why would I use a gem, isn't there a standard way in Ruby?

Comment: The second link I posted, describes 5 ways that are standard in Ruby. The 6th way, using the gem, is the only one that gets you both the status and the output, and does it quite nicely I think.

Comment: *The 6th way, using the gem, is the only one that gets you both the status and the output*...Not true.

Comment: As shown by the other answers here, you are correct. I have definitely learned something myself!

Answer (score 0):

```
#my_prog.rb
puts 'hello'
exit 10
```

...

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen2("ruby my_prog.rb") do |stdin, stdout, wait_thr|
  puts stdout.read
  status_obj = wait_thr.value # Process::Status object returned.
  puts status_obj.exitstatus
end


--output:--
hello
10
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want exception as an instance of class Exception to be able to
>   re-raise it, not just a string.

You can do this:

```
#my_prog.rb

puts 'hello'
10/0
```

...

```
require 'open3'

begin
  Open3.popen3("ruby my_prog.rb") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
    puts stdout.read
    status_obj = wait_thr.value  #Process::Status object returned.
    puts status_obj.exitstatus

    error = stderr.read
    md = error.match(/\w+ Error/xm)

    if md
      e = Exception.const_get(md[0]).new if md 
      p e.class.ancestors
      raise e
    end

  end
rescue ZeroDivisionError
  puts 'Hey, someone divided by zero!'
end

--output:--
hello
1
[ZeroDivisionError, StandardError, Exception, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Hey, someone divided by zero!
```

Unfortunately, there are several exceptions whose names do not end in 'Error'--but you can modify the code to search for those specifically in the error message.