# rails controller returning nil response while running casperjs test cases with shell script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, shell, ruby-on-rails-4, casperjs

I am using casper test cases with a rails application, for running the test case I am using following command.

```
result = `cd #{Rails.root.join}/casper && casperjs test #{params[:file]}.js`
```

The above mentioned code is working fine on development environment(webrick) but if I run this on staging(nginx+passenger) then I am getting nil response within seconds that means that the script is running asynchronously, I need to run this synchronously so that I can send a JSON response to the client. the method that I am using for providing response is as follow.

```
def test
   @result = `cd #{Rails.root.join}/casper && casperjs test #{params[:file]}.js`
   render json: JSON.parse(@result) 
end
```