# Rails storing systemcall in variable?

Tags: ruby

Hi How can I save a system call in a variable?

I want to do something like that:

```
@info[0] = system "ruby -v".to_s
```

Comment: I edited your question to remove the Rails tags since this seems to only be about Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
@info = `ruby -v` # or %[ruby -v]
p @info
```

Take a look into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby).

Comment: sulution is %x[ruby -v]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IO.popen](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-popen)

```
@info = IO.popen("ruby -v").read
@info
=> "ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]\n"
```