# Getting the value of a system call

Tags: ruby, system-calls

I'm trying to get a value from a system call in Ruby:

```
distro = system('lsb_release -is')
distver = system('lsb_release -rs | cut  -c1-2')
```

I thought the return from the `lsb_release` comes into the variables. But if I'm made a `puts distro` or `puts distver` I'm just getting true.

Is there any way to get the value from them?

Comment: It has already been asked before lots of times. Here's one answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with

```
d = `date`
e = IO.popen("date").read
```

Take some time also with `IO.popen`, `IO.popen2`, `IO.popen3`.