# how to get the output of a shell command in ruby

Tags: ruby

In an `irb` console these lines execute as I expect:

```
require 'open3'
stdout, stderr, exit_status = Open3.capture3('clang-format < tmp')
puts stdout
puts stderr
puts exit_status
```

That is, the output of command `clang-format < tmp` is printed out through `stdout`; for `stderr` the value is `nil` and for `exit_status` the output is `pid 28181 exit 0`.

However, when I execute them in a script the output for `stdout`is empty, but the value of `exit_status` is printed out.

Why that? Could someone please illuminate me?

Comment: What do stderr and exit_status print?

Comment: I tried the same thing and got the expected result. Make sure the tmp file that clang-format is referencing inside the script is the same tmp file referenced from irb. That's the only thing I could think of, you have a duplicate tmp file somewhere that is empty

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby i think this is what you are looking for.