# How to pass a value from a C++ executable to a Rails app?

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, command-line

I have a Rails app that runs a C++ executable from the command line. I'm able to print the C++ `cout` to the command line, but I'd like to assign it back to a variable, `output =` in a Rails controller.

Is this possible?

Below is a simplified example of my Rails controller action and C++ `.cpp` to help explain the question.

**Rails controller:**

```
def get_variable
  system("cd ~/workspace/OutputTest/src && ./output.bin")
end
```

Note I've already compiled and created a C++ executable file named `output.bin`.

**C++ file:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!!!";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm familiar with Rails (not necessarily running files from the command line through Rails), but a complete newb to C++.

Any guidance would be very appreciated. If there is another approach I should be taking completely, that would also be very helpful to know.

I would prefer not to do this inline, as I'd like to do a lot more in C++ once I can solve this initial step.

## UPDATE

The best solution I've come up with so far is writing a string to a `.txt` in C++, and then using `File.read()` in Rails. But it doesn't feel scalable, or give flexibility over data structure.

So I'm still wondering if there is a more straightforward way, like somehow keeping the value in memory for Rails to access it. Not sure though.

Comment: Maybe this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby ? But anyway I think this might be a bad design and you may want to have a look at RPC or C-to-ruby wrapper like swig which wraps C function(s) into ruby.

Comment: Another solution may be create a listener socket in Rails and then send data to this socket from c++

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have already tried this, but there is a backtick operator in ruby, which returns the output of a command as a string.

example:

```
def system_date
  `date`
end
puts system_date #=> "Wed Nov 16 18:59:28 CET 2016"
```

in your case it would be

```
def get_variable
  `~/workspace/OutputTest/src/output.bin`
end
```

Comment: I agree that backticks are a good choice to solve this problem. I just made your code follow common Ruby idioms (removed the `return` that is not needed and the empty parenthesis)

Answer (score 0):

The best idea I thought of is running the C++ app, piping (`|`) the input to rails (if that works) and doing `$stdin.gets()`. I'm not a ruby expert, and I haven't used it much, but I think it should work. Try

```
./cppapp | rubyapp
```

on a bash terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture an output of your programm with pipe:

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello world!!!";
  return 0;
}
```

Compile it: `$ g++ test.cpp -o hello`

test.rb:

```
var = IO.popen("./hello") do |cmd|
  cmd.read
end

puts var

#=> "Hello world!!!"
```

More information about pipe reading can be found in documentation: [IO.popen](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-c-popen)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the back-tick operator to capture the output of command line executions in ruby.

```
irb(main):008:0> x = `echo foo`
=> "foo\n"
```