# Ruby and shell : get the same output with ls

Tags: ruby, shell

I got a folder with the following zip files :

> 13162.zip  14864.zip  19573.zip  20198.zip

In console, when i run :

```
cd my_folder; echo `ls *{.zip,.ZIP}`
```

I got the following output (which is perfect) :

```
ls: cannot access *.ZIP: No such file or directory
13162.zip 14864.zip 19573.zip 20198.zip
```

Now when in ruby i try the same :

```
cmd= "cd my_folder; echo `ls {*.zip,*.ZIP}`";
puts `#{cmd}`
```

It only display :

```
ls: cannot access {*.zip,*.ZIP}: No such file or directory
 => nil
```

I try this solution :
 [Getting output of system() calls in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby)

But it seem not work in my case.

How can i get the same output in ruby and in shell ?

Comment: In `irb` console type `cmd = \`cd Downloads; ls *.zip *.ZIP\`` followed by `puts cmd`

Comment: What do you want to achive? Your code isn't valid ruby code. Please, provide correct code.

Comment: Have you considered using Ruby methods like [`Dir.chdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) and [`Dir.glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob)?

Comment: Imran Ali : Solve my concern! Thx. (Dir.chdir => With the existing codebase i have to work to, it's not possible but it's of course a better idea)

Comment: You're using brace expansion. This is supported by your interactive shell (bash), but not by your system shell (probably dash) which ruby uses. You should write this in Ruby instead of using a shell, and @EricDuminil shows how. You could technically have used the sh equivalent `ls *.zip *.ZIP` or commonly `ls *.[zZ][iI][pP]` but Eric's answer is much better.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby Only

You can use `Dir.glob` with `File::FNM_CASEFOLD` for case-insensitive search :

```
Dir.chdir 'my_folder' do
  Dir.glob('*.zip', File::FNM_CASEFOLD).each do |zip_file|
    puts zip_file
  end
end

#=> 
# 19573.zip
# 13162.zip
# 14864.zip
# 20198.zip
# 12345.zIp
```

## Ruby + bash

You can use `find` for case-insensitive search :

```
paths = `find my_folder -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.zip'`.split
#=> ["my_folder/19573.zip", "my_folder/13162.zip", "my_folder/14864.zip", "my_folder/20198.zip", "my_folder/12345.zIp"]
```

`-printf '%P'` can also be used to only display the filenames :

```
files = `find my_folder -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.zip' -printf '%P\n'`.split
#=> ["19573.zip", "13162.zip", "14864.zip", "20198.zip", "12345.zIp"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work directly on the terminal:

```
echo 'system("ls *ZIP,*zip")' | ruby
```

or create a ruby file with the following contents

```
system("cd my_folder; ls {*.zip,*.ZIP}")
```

and then execute it. Once you write **ls**, you don't need **echo**!